# Changing scope variable from directive in my case

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So i cant figure out how to change a scope variable from the directive.

I want to set the variable **signuptoggle** back to FALSE when the animation finishes, so it will load the first LOGIN screen every time i press LOGIN button/Link.

Directive Template:

```
<!-- Login -->
<div ng-controller="loginController" class="modal" id="loginDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginDialog">
    <div ng-show="!signuptoggle" class="modal-dialog loginDialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" id="closeLoginDialog" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><img class="img-loginlogo" src="images/logo-SMgrey.png"></h4>
            <h3>Don't have an account yet?<a id="signupbtn" href="#" ng-click="signuptoggle = true">Sign up</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="login-form-input-area">
                        <input type="email" id="sign-in-email" name="sign-up-email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-form-input-area">
                        <input type="password" id="sign-in-password" name="sign-up-password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-form-input-area">
                        <input class="btn btn-default login-btn" type="submit" value="SIGN IN">
                    </div>
                </form>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p class="login-separator"><span class="login-separator-mid">or</span></p>
                <p>Sign in with your social account.</p>
                <div class="login-social-icons">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/fb-social-icon.png" title="Sign up with Facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/g-social-icon.png" title="Sign up with Gmail"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/tw-social-icon.png" title="Sign up with Twitter"></a>
                </div>
                <p class="login-terms">By continuing you agree to Social Markt's <a href="#">Terms of Service</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div ng-show="signuptoggle" class="modal-dialog loginDialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" id="closeSignUpDialog" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><img class="img-loginlogo" src="images/logo-SMgrey.png"></h4>
            <h3>Already have an account?<a id="signinbtn" href="#" ng-click="signuptoggle = false">Sign in</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="login-form-input-area">
                        <input type="text" id="sign-up-first-name" name="sign-up-first-name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        <input type="text" id="sign-up-last-name" name="sign-up-last-name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-form-input-area">
                        <input type="email" id="sign-up-email" name="sign-up-email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-form-input-area">
                        <input type="password" id="sign-up-password" name="sign-up-password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <input class="btn btn-default signup-btn" type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
                    </div>
                </form>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p class="login-separator"><span class="login-separator-mid">or</span></p>
                <p>Sign up faster by connecting your social account.</p>
                <div class="login-social-icons">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/fb-social-icon.png" title="Sign up with Facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/g-social-icon.png" title="Sign up with Gmail"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/tw-social-icon.png" title="Sign up with Twitter"></a>
                </div>
                <p class="login-terms">By continuing you agree to Social Markt's <a href="#">Terms of Service</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Custom element:

```
<home-login-dialog data-id="login" model="$parent"></home-login-dialog>
```

Directive:

```
socialMarkt.directive("homeLoginDialog", [function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/homeLoginDialogView.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        angular.element('#' + attrs.id).click(function(){
            var animationNameIn = "in animated bounceInDown";
            var atEnd = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";

            angular.element('#loginDialog').addClass(animationNameIn).modal('show').one(atEnd, function(){
                angular.element(this).removeClass(animationNameIn);
            });
        });

        angular.element('#closeLoginDialog').click(function(){

            var atEnd = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";

            angular.element('#loginDialog').addClass("animated bounceOutUp").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){
                    angular.element(this).removeClass("animated bounceOutUp")
                }).one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){
                    angular.element('#loginDialog').modal('hide');
                });
        });


        angular.element('#closeSignUpDialog').click(function(){

            var atEnd = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";

            angular.element('#loginDialog').addClass("animated bounceOutUp").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){
                    angular.element(this).removeClass("animated bounceOutUp")
                }).one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){
                    angular.element('#loginDialog').modal('hide');

                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.signuptoggle = false;
                    });

                });
        });
    }
}}]);
```

Cotroller:

```
socialMarkt.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);
```

As you can see im using jquery (angular.element) to take care of the animations.

Im using **ng-click** to change the value of the variable **signuptoggle**  and **ng-show** to monitor the **signuptoggle** variable in order to display the DIV or not.

The problem is, when i click SIGN IN to open the SIGN IN screen and switch to SIGN UP screen, it stays on SIGN UP screen even after closing the window ( floating modal ). so Im trying to set the variable **signuptoggle** back to false whenever a close the modal window.

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: the controller is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I changed the way it was changing the screens to use the controller as well.